# Punctuation in dialogue that addressed more than one person

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, quotations

So I got a question regarding comma in speech. Here is an example of the sentence:

“Wait a minute.” I hurriedly shouted to stop him and said to her, “Who invited that blockhead to this party?"

In this sentence, I shouted to the first guy which should have ended the first direct speech with a comma, right? But I see that it was ended with a period inside a novel I read. So I don't know which one is correct.

Although, I know for a fact that a speech disrupted in the middle like this:
"Hey," I said, "she will be going as well." Has two commas.

Comment: "Wait a minute.” and “Who invited that blockhead to this party?" are two separate sentences addressed to two separate people. There may be a significant pause between them. It's not even clear that "Wait a minute" is what the narrator is shouting; they may say that to themselves then shout something else. It's not an elegant construction, but there's nothing really wrong with it.

Comment: So even if "Wait a minute." is still shouted to the first guy, in this construction, ending the first dialogue in a period in not wrong, right? I see.

Comment: I agree; the dialogue tag seems inappropriately distanced from the initial quote (direct speech). I'd prefer << “Wait a minute!” I hurriedly shouted to stop him, and said to her[,] “Who invited that blockhead to this party?" >> I've never seen a proscription of two addressees in the same sentence, two differently directed sentences, though one needs to maintain clarity. << “Wait a minute!” I hurriedly shouted to stop him. And then said to her, “Who invited that blockhead to this party?" >> is also possible, but inserts a major pause (as would a dash). A style choice.